# Middle school book about kid who sees an evil version of himself

Tags: story-identification, books

This is very vague and you probably won’t know but I vaguely remembered a book series that had 3 books (I think). In one of the books the main character goes on a road trip and sees himself in the woods, in another one of the books he sees ancient pyramids. The book cover is also similar to *“The Last Kids on Earth”*, it has a bunch of colors and the main character is on the cover. And the main character on the cover may also have had glasses.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: The main chsracter seeing an evil version of himself is Edgar Allen Poe's *William Wilson*.  But none of the rest matches.